# Bitcoin Bech32 address validation

Tags: segregated-witness, bech32-address

Bech32 addresses start with `bc1` on the main net and `tb1` on the test net.
I want to know whether a segwit address is valid or not.
How can I check that segwit addresses are correctly inserted?

Comment: Are you looking for a specification, or example implementations, or libraries that can do this for you?

Comment: Please provide more information what you're trying to achieve, what you have tried, and how the outcome differed from your expectations? Pieter has some good pointers what would help us. Also, if you're looking to implement it, have you read the bech32 specification in [BIP173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki), and the bech32m specification in [BIP350](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0350.mediawiki)?

Comment: Think they just want sipa's bech32 site? https://bitcoin.sipa.be/bech32/demo/demo.html

Comment: @Murch I want to understand and implement this in a wallet. users may lock their coins or assets using a wrong address.

Comment: @PieterWuille If you know any java implementation of that, it would be really helping.

Comment: There's a pull request for a java implementation [here](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/pull/46), but it would need to be reviewed and tested before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bech32 is specified in [BIP173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki). Native segwit outputs version 0 (P2WPKH and P2WSH) use bech32 addresses.
Native segwit outputs version 1+ (P2TR) use the improved bech32m for their addresses. Bech32m is specified in [BIP350](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0350.mediawiki).

Besides the specifications the BIPs contain test vectors which should be deployed in their entirety to verify any implementation.

A Java implementation of bech32(m) addresses can be found here in [bitcoinj](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/44d0576ce4310a3d6f1859964e391fa8d981d409/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/base/Bech32.java).

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin core command to validate an address: https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/validateaddress.html